# What annotation to use to wrap a method in a database transaction

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions, wildfly, java-ee-7

I have a web service that persists data and one of the methods needs to be within a database transaction. In substance, it looks like this:

```
public abstract class ControllerBase {
  //this is a method that needs to run in a transaction
  void batchUpsert(/* ... */) {
    try {
      sql.query("BEGIN").execute();
      sql.query("LOCK TABLE " + tableName + " IN EXCLUSIVE MODE").execute();
      //do some stuff
    } finally {
      sql.query("COMMIT").execute();
    }
  }
}
```

And the web service is defined in a sub class and calls the method above:

```
@Path("symbology")
@Stateless
public class SymbologyController extends ControllerBase {
  @PUT
  @Path("upsert_symbology")
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Response upsertSymbology(List<SymbologyRecord> symbology) {
    batchUpsert(SYMBOLOGY, symbology, SYMBOLOGY.SHORT_NAME);
    return Response.ok().build();
  }
}
```

That does not feel right because the transaction part should be managed by the container rather than me sending `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` statements.

So I removed them and added an `@TransactionAttribute` annotation on the `batchUpsert` method:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
void batchUpsert(/* ... */) {
  sql.query("LOCK TABLE " + tableName + " IN EXCLUSIVE MODE").execute();
  //do some stuff
}
```

But the container (wildfly) does not seem to create a transaction and I get an exception:

> ERROR: LOCK TABLE can only be used in transaction blocks

I also tried the `@TransactionAttribute` annotation but it did not work either.

**How am I supposed to let wildfly know that it needs to wrap my method in a database transaction?**

---

***EDIT***

I have just realised that the transaction status is active:

```
@Resource TransactionSynchronizationRegistry tsr;


@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
void batchUpsert(/* ... */) {
  LOG.info("Transaction active? {}", tsr.getTransactionStatus() == Status.STATUS_ACTIVE);
  //...
}
```

outputs true. Isn't this supposed to have run the equivalent of a `BEGIN` statement at the database level?

Comment: What is `sql`? It's probably not enrolled to the current transaction. Have you considered using a JTA managed `EntityManager` instead?

Comment: @Benjamin I am using JOOQ and `sql` is essentially a thin wrapper around a `DataSource`. The connection is provided by `@Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/jdbc/ws") private javax.sql.DataSource postgres;`. I have never used JTA so not sure what it brings. Is there a way to enroll the data source to the current transaction?

Comment: JTA brings transaction management, `TransactionSynchronizationRegistry` is part of JTA. If your datasource is declared with JTA enabled in wildfly: `<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/jdbc/ws" ...>` then it should work. Otherwise i don't know what this JOOQ wrapper you are using performs... You may try directly using the datasource?

Comment: @Benjamin That was the problem: jta was not enabled on the datasource (not sure why). Feel free to post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that your datasource is declared with JTA enabled in wildfly:

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/jdbc/ws" ...>
```

Answer (score 1):

I generally separate my Database logic into different facades.

```
@Stateless
public void DBFacade{

  @TransactionAttribute(REQUIRES_NEW(
  public void doSomethingIntransaction(){}
}

@Stateless
@Path("/path")
public class MyFrontendService{
  @EJB
  private DBFacade dbFacade;

  @PUT
  @Path("upsert_symbology")
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public void updateUserData(){
    dbFacade.doSomething();
  }

}
```

Why must you do it this way?
Because if you dont, there is no way the container will intercept the invocation of `batchUsert()` since you are invocking the method directly. However, if you use ejb injection, the injected instance is a proxy to the actual bean, when you invoke a method on the proxy, they container intercepts it, decides if it requires an active transaction, and then calls the actual method which it holds reference to. This is the only ejb way. You must delegate the actual invocation.

Comment: My code worked as is - the problem is that jta was not enabled on the datasource.